# How can I get the quotient of a division in lua?

Tags: math, lua, roblox, luau

For my game in roblox, I need the quotient of a division. For example the quotient of 20/3 is 6 and 40/2 is 20. Is there a way to do this using a function?

Comment: Since Lua 5.3, you can use `//` for floor division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at math.modf(a/b), which will return two values, the intergral and the fractional remainder.

```
a = 20
b = 3
q, _ = math.modf(a/b)
print(q)
```

will result in `6`

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need `math.modf` here since you don't care about the fractional remainder. It would probably be more efficient and more straightforward to go with

```lua
quotient = math.floor(dividend / divisor)
```

instead (which is simply `dividend // divisor` since Lua 5.3 as lhf has pointed out; Luau, being based on 5.1, does not seem to provide `//` however); if you wanted to go with only operators, you could also write

```lua
quotient = (dividend - (dividend % divisor)) / divisor
```